# Angular parameter being passed to my controller is always false

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-routing, asp.net-core-routing

Not sure if I have the routing or syntax right as I'm a little new to Angular routing.
But the 'isPartial' parameter is always false.

Here is my code in Angular/Typescript where I'm calling my webservice controller.
I'm passing an id and a boolean 'isPartial', the id comes in fine but the isPartial is always false

```js
// .ts file
this.webService.add(this.claim.id, true)
  .subscribe(result => {
    // do some stuff
  }, error => {
    // take care of error
  });

// web service 
add(id: number, isPartial: boolean): Observable <any> {
  return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'webservice/add/' + id, isPartial);
}

// my route
{
  path: 'claim/:id',
  component: ClaimComponent,
  resolve: {
    claim: ClaimResolver
  },
  canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChanges]
},
```

here is my controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WebServiceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("add/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id, bool isPartial) 
    {
       // isPartial is always false
    }
}
```

Comment: from where you are calling `add` method? can you post the code from where the service is calling `add` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have configured two possible solutions for your condition.

**Solution 1**: Set your request `Content-Type` to `application/json` instead of the default `Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8`

ts:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
//...
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
add(id: number, isPartial: boolean): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'webservice/add/' + id, isPartial, httpOptions);
}
```

controller:

```
[HttpPost("add/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id, [FromBody]bool isPartial)
```

**Solution 2**: wrap `isPartial` in a model,it is recommend if you have multiple parameters.

ts:

```
add(id: number, isPartial: boolean): Observable <any> {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'webservice/add/' + id, { 'isPartial': isPartial });
}
```

http.post(baseUrl + 'api/SampleData/add/' + id, { 'isPartial': isPartial })

controller:

```
public class myModel
{
    public bool isPartial { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost("add/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(int id, [FromBody]myModel myModel)
```

Answer (score 0):

change your parameter binding in C# controller  like this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class WebServiceController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("add/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add( [FromUri]int id, [FromBody]bool isPartial) 
    {
       // isPartial is always false
    }
}
```